# Laravel Return Download did not work

Tags: php, excel, csv, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I am trying to create Excel CSV Sheet and then download it.

CSV file is created perfectly but unfortunately download did not work.

```
public function download_csv(Request $request) {
        if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
            if (Auth::check()) {

             $user_id = Auth::id();
             $customer_id = Auth::user()->customer_id;

             $suppliers = Supplier::where('is_active', 1)->get();

             $dataCSV = array();
             $main = array();
             $cnt = 1;
             foreach($suppliers as $m) {
                $main['S. No'] = $cnt++;
                $main['Name'] = $m->Name;
                array_push($dataCSV, $main);
                $cnt++;
             }

             $csv_name = $user_id.'_'.rand(10000, 99999);
             $csv =  Excel::create($csv_name, function($excel) use($dataCSV) {
                $excel->sheet('Sheetname', function($sheet) use($dataCSV) {
                   $sheet->fromArray($dataCSV);
                });
             });
             $csv->store('csv', storage_path('excel/exports/'.$customer_id.'/'));
             $file = storage_path('excel/exports/'.$customer_id.'/'.$csv_name.'.csv');

            $headers = array(
                'Content-Type: application/csv',
              );

            return Response::download($file, $user_id.'.csv', $headers);

          }
        }
    }
```

I did not understand where is the issue.

Any Help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: For download, you have to refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

Have you used the response class? 
`use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;`

option 2: try downloading it via a different method: 
`return response()->download($pathToFile, $name, $headers);`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/responses#file-downloads